# Remove items from one array if not in the second array

Tags: javascript, arrays, adobe-indesign

I state that I have tried for a long time before writing this post.

For an InDesign script, I'm working with two array of ListItems. Now I'm trying to remove the items of one array that aren't in the second array, but i'm stuck.

Given that I use the following javascript code (it works great) to remove the equal items between the two arrays :

```
function check_dupli(arr_A, arr_B) {
    for(var i = arr_B.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        for(var j = 0; j < arr_A.length; j++) {
            if(arr_B[i] === arr_A[j]) {
                arr_B.splice(i, 1);
            }
        }
    }
    arr_B.sort();
}

arr_A = ["a","b","d","f","g"]
arr_B = ["a","c","f","h"]

check_dupli(arr_A, arr_B) --> arr_B = ["c","h"]
check_dupli(arr_B, arr_A) --> arr_B = ["b","d","g"]
```

I thought to modify it in order to ignore the items not that are not in both arrays, and to obtain what I want, but something is going wrong because I also get the unwanted data :

```
function get_dupli(arr_A, arr_B, arr_C) {
    for(var e = arr_B.length - 1; e >= 0; e--) {
        for(var k = 0; k < arr_A.length; k++) {
            if(arr_B[e] === arr_A[k]) {
                arr_C.push(arr_B[e]);
            }
        }
    }
    arr_C.sort();
}

arr_A = ["a","b","d","f","g"]
arr_B = ["a","g","k"]
arr_C = ["h"]

get_dupli(arr_A, arr_B, arr_C) --> arr_C = ["a","g","h","k"] instead of --> ["a","g","h"]
get_dupli(arr_B, arr_A, arr_C) --> arr_C = ["a","b","d","f","g","h"] instead of --> ["a","g","h"]
```

Where I'm wrong? There is another way in pure javascript to solve the problem?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: If you're just working with two arrays as is stated, then why introduce a third array in the first place?

Comment: Your code appears to work: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/oejaxhyj/1/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Opsss .... I believed I had given the answer and closed this post ... sorry !!!

Despite all the checks I made, the failure of the mine as your script was caused by a stupid mistake ... the array arr_A passed to the function was a modified copy of the original array.

Thank you all for your concern and help. Sorry again ...

Answer (score 3):

You can make use of `Array.prototype.filter` and `Array.prototype.concat` to simply it:

```js
arr_A = ["a","b","d","f","g"]
arr_B = ["a","g","k"]
arr_C = ["h"]

function getCommonItems(arrayA, arrayB, result) {
 result = result || [];
 result = result.concat(arrayA.filter(function(item) {
            return arrayB.indexOf(item) >= 0;    
          }));
 return result.sort();
}

alert(getCommonItems(arr_A, arr_B, arr_C).join(", "));
alert(getCommonItems(arr_B, arr_A, arr_C).join(", "));
```

For the first scenario:

```js
arr_A = ["a","b","d","f","g"]
arr_B = ["a","c","f","h"]

function getDifference(arrayA, arrayB, result) {
 return arrayB.filter(function(item) {
            return arrayA.indexOf(item) === -1;    
  }).sort();
}

alert(getDifference(arr_A, arr_B).join(", "));
alert(getDifference(arr_B, arr_A).join(", "));
```

Comment: Amit Joki I entered a third array to be sure not to alter the first two. Think of it as a temporary array.

Comment: John S Exactly, on JSfiddle working properly but trying it with InDesign it doesn't : the result also includes what should be ignored.

Comment: OddDev I had already carried out tests with the code as what you suggest, but the result is the same as the previous one.

Comment: Since my reasoning appears to be right, the problem could be due to InDesign? If so, why the code that I use to remove equal items it works properly?

Comment: @AlessioTonarelli Sorry mate I don't have much idea about InDesign. But yes, your code was correct. Something else is causing the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Do it like this:

```js
//the array which will loose some items
var ar1 = ["a", "b", "c"];
//the array which is the template
var ar2 = ["d", "a", "b"];

var tmpar = [];

for(var i = 0; i < ar1.length; i++){
  if(ar2.indexOf(ar1[i]) !== -1){
    tmpar.push(ar1[i]);
  }
}

ar1 = tmpar;

alert(ar1);
```

We create a temporary array to store the valid values.

We make sure that the index of the value from the first array is not "-1". If it's "-1" the index is not found and therefore the value is not valid! We store everything which is not "-1" (so we store every valid value).

Answer (score 0):

```js
Array.prototype.contains =  function ( object )
{
 var i = 0, n = this.length;
 
 for ( i = 0 ; i < n ; i++ )
 {
  if ( this[i] === object )
  {
   return true;
  }
 }
 
 return false;
}

Array.prototype.removeItem = function(value, global) {
 var idx;
 var  n = this.length;
 while ( n-- ) {
  if ( value instanceof RegExp && value.test ( this[n]) 
  || this[n] === value ) {
   this.splice (n, 1 );
   if ( !global ) return this;
  }
 }
 return this;
};

arr_A = ["a","b","d","f","g"];
arr_B = ["a","c","f","h"];

var item
while ( item = arr_A.pop() ) {
 arr_B.contains ( item ) && arr_B.removeItem ( item  );
}

arr_B;
```

Comment: The result of your code is the opposite of what I need : [“c“,“h“] instead of ["a","f"].

Answer (score 0):

```js
arr_A = ["a","b","d","f","g"];
arr_B = ["a","c","f","h"];
var newArr = [];
var item
while ( item = arr_B.shift() ) {
 arr_A.contains ( item ) && newArr[ newArr.length ] = item ;
}
newArr;// ["a", "f"];
```

Comment: This version of the script works well but, like the others, when I insert it into my full project no longer works. Next weekend I will do a thorough check of my code, I suspect that I'm missing something that prevents proper operation of your suggestions.

Comment: A prototype function needs to be placed prior to any calls. Place the functions at the beginning of your code and try again.